# Show elements in struct in c

Tags: c

Hello stackoverflow community! 
 I'm novice in C, so I'm starting to work with structures and try to resolve an exercice. I need to show all elements in structures **s_stock_str** but at the beginning I have an error when I try to show all elements and I dont know why, can you tell me why and where is my error please?

```
#include "ft_stock_str.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int ft_strlen(char *s)
{
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    while (s[i])
        i++;
    return (i);
}

char    *ft_strcpy(char *dst, char *src)
{
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    while (src[i])
    {
        dst[i] = src[i];
        i++;
    }
    dst[i] = 0;
    return (dst);
}

char    *ft_strdup(char *s1)
{
    char    *s2;

    s2 = malloc(ft_strlen(s1) + 1);
    if (!s2)
        return (NULL);
    ft_strcpy(s2, s1);
    return (s2);
}

struct s_stock_str  *ft_strs_to_tab(int ac, char **av)
{
    int i;
    struct s_stock_str      *tab;

    tab = malloc(sizeof(t_stock_str) * ac + 1);
    if (!tab)
        return (NULL);
    i = 0;
    while (i < ac - 1)
    {
        tab[i].size = ft_strlen(av[i]);
        tab[i].str = ft_strdup(av[i]);
        tab[i].copy = ft_strdup(av[i]);
        i++;
    }
    tab[i].str = 0;
    return (tab);
}

void    ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

void    ft_putnbr(int nb)
{
    unsigned int    n;

    n = -nb;
    if (nb < 0)
    {
        n = -nb;
        ft_putchar('-');
    }
    if (n >= 10)
        ft_putnbr(n / 10);
    ft_putchar('0' + (n % 10));
}

void    ft_show_tab(struct s_stock_str *par)
{
    unsigned int    i;

    i = 0;
    while (par[i].str != 0)
    {
        write(1, par[i].str, par[i].size);
        write(1, "\n", 1);
        ft_putnbr(par[i].size);
        write(1, "\n", 1);
        write(1, par[i].copy, par[i].size);
        write(1, "\n", 1);
        i++;
    }
}

int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ft_show_tab(ft_strs_to_tab(argc, argv));
    return (0);
}
```

EDIT: struct.h :

```
typedef struct s_stock_str
{
int size;
char *str;
char *copy;
} t_stock_str;
```

Error in interest: zsh: segmentation fault  ./a.out

Comment: Could you please add your struct definition ?

Comment: What error?  You need to show us the error, too.

Comment: You get a segmentation fault. That usually means a pointer pointing nowhere or an access outside of the area pointed by it. On which line EXACTLY does it occur. You can easily find the line by using a debugger and running your code step by step.

Comment: The (unnecessary) recursion in `ft_putnbr` never ends. Use your debugger or put at least  some printfs printing relevant variable values at appropriate places.

Comment: my function putnbr work finely

Comment: @hugohg no it doesnt. Put `ft_putnbr(5)` (and nothing else)  in your main function and [check yourself](https://www.ideone.com/DL8fkr).

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I put - in first attribution.

Answer (score 0):

So i found 2 issues:

Firstly, your ft_putnbr doesn't seem to work, and when i fixed it, it worked for me, so here is my version:

```c
int ft_abs(int nb)
{
    return (nb > 0 ? nb : -nb);
}

void    ft_putnbr(int nb)
{
    int    n;

    n = nb;
    if (n == -2147483648)
    {
        write (1, "-2147483648", 11);
        return ;
    }
    if (nb < 0)
        ft_putchar('-');
    if (ft_abs(n) >= 10)
        ft_putnbr(ft_abs(n) / 10);
    ft_putchar('0' + (ft_abs(n) % 10));
}
```

Also, this is wrong:

```c
tab = malloc(sizeof(t_stock_str) * ac + 1);
```

You are allocating memory for a struct, but only adding a single byte to the end. It should be like this:

```c
tab = malloc(sizeof(t_stock_str) * ac + sizeof(t_stock_str));
// or
tab = malloc(sizeof(t_stock_str) * (ac + 1));
```

And after that you should change `while (i < ac - 1)` to `while (i < ac)` in your `ft_strs_to_tab` function. Otherwise it just ignores last element of the array